# PHP encrpyt, first 16 of string gone after decrypt with python

Tags: php, python, encryption, aes, php-openssl

After encrypting with PHP 7, whenever I decrypt using Python 2, first 16 characters are gone..

IE:

before encryption:

THIS IS A TEXT THAT NEED TO BE ENCRYPTED AND ALSO NEED TO BE DECRYPT USING PYTHON (OR OTHER LANGAUGE).

after decryption:

HAT NEED TO BE ENCRYPTED AND ALSO NEED TO BE DECRYPT USING PYTHON (OR OTHER LANGAUGE)

**PHP to encrypt**

```
$method = 'AES-256-CBC';

$key = hash('sha256', 'password', true);

$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

$enc = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

$encrypted = base64_encode($enc);
```

**Python to decrypt**

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, key): 
        self.bs = 32
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]
```

so if I encrypt this in PHP (decrypting it on PHP works fine)

THIS IS A TEXT THAT NEED TO BE ENCRYPTED AND ALSO NEED TO BE DECRYPT USING PYTHON (OR OTHER LANGAUGE).

but i decrpyt it on Python, the result is missing first 16 parts of string

HAT NEED TO BE ENCRYPTED AND ALSO NEED TO BE DECRYPT USING PYTHON (OR OTHER LANGAUGE)

Comment: In the PHP-code the concatenation of the IV is missing. The Python-code expects the IV before the ciphertext. Replace the last line in the PHP-code with `$encrypted = base64_encode($iv.$enc);`

Comment: Thank you @Topaco, is there a way we can decode this without adding iv on php part? like changes in Python part? if not that is okay, but I hope there is a way..

Comment: The IV is mandatory for decryption, i.e. the IV must be made available to the decryption code in some form. The IV doesn't have to be secret. Therefore the usual way is simply to concatenate with the encrypted data. As an alternative to concatenation, the IV can also be passed in the Python-code as a parameter, e.g. in Base64-encoded format, besides the encrypted data.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to retrieve the contents of the first 16 bytes for existing encrypted ciphertext. The IV works as a one-time-pad in that case, and OTP's are secure if the underlying random number generator is secure, and it is. You need to include the IV as already suggested.